# How can I forbid to switch to other applications except mine phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile

I am writing application using PhoneGap **I have to block a user switch to all other applications when my app is running**. A user will have to submit some button to close my app. It is obligatory to use, because user should not have the access to browsers and other similar apps.

Besides, he should not access to all notifications from other applications.
So my application should work like *"air mode"*, but have to forbid not only the calls and network, but all activity in background, in that way a user will work only with one app for a definite time.

It is possible to do?
Thanks for all

Comment: Afaik you'll not be able to forbid sth like that. Why should Google allow you to forbid the user to change the application. We don't have to talk about apple here, of course they don't do that also.

Comment: Is any way to block notifications from other applications at least?

Comment: Nope, as far as i know this will not be possible without acitivating the airplane mode

Comment: bad news for me. May be you know sth about clearing the buffer when app will start?

Comment: ...here again, afaik no. You can may use a trick here and hook onto the menubutton event in cordova. Therefore you would use an eventListener as described here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#menubutton and oncall you terminate the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found information about **Guided Access** for iOS. It looks pretty cool for my purpose to "limits your device to a single app and lets you control which app features are available."

But I have not the tools (may be plugins or smth else) for PhoneGap how can I manage this setting. Will be awesome to get read-only property whether the setting is On or Off.

P.S

There is phonegap plugin which allowed to check if application under Guided Access or not - mobile-accessibility

Links:

[About Guided Access](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612)

[Mobile accessibility phonegap plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility)